Code Block - overflow border

I wanna (1) use the colour and (2) avoid code overflow the border
any suggestions for debugging?

I don't know why the code doesn't work and tried // as quick fix as deadline coming, but failed. The simplified code is as below.
It doesn't look exactly the same as the photo as the original files are many files of thesis, I cannot post them all. But the problem of code overflow the border is the same.
Thanks for any suggestions!
\documentclass[
    ngerman,
        11pt,
    %twoside,
    BCOR=8mm,
    headings=normal,
    parskip=half,
    headsepline,
    automark,
    listof=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
    %,captions=tableabove
    %draft
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
%%%\usepackage{babel}
%
\ifluatex
 % LuaLaTeX
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 % \setmainfont{Arial}
 \usepackage{selnolig}
\else
 % PdfLaTeX
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
%
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlang1}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl} 

\lstdefinestyle{myLaTeX}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=TeX,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    frame=single,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    tabsize=2,
    morekeywords={
        lstdefinestyle,
        footnotesize,
        ttfamily,
        color,
    },
}

\lstdefinestyle{myBasic}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    escapechar={|_},
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
}

\lstset{style=myLaTeX}

%=== styles =======================================

\newcommand{\tb}{\textbackslash}
%
\newcommand{\comm}[1]{\enquote{\texttt{\tb #1}}}
%
\newcommand{\param}[1]{%
    $\langle$\textrm{\textit{#1}}$\rangle$%
}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
  language=HTML,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=lines
}

% Define listing settings for HTML
\lstdefinestyle{html}{ 
breaklines=true, 
postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}, 
umbers=left, 
stepnumber=1, 
numbersep=10pt, 
numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
keepspaces=true 
}

\begin{lstlisting}[html]
<cite> The order was easy to place and everything was delivered perfectly.</cite>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}




Can you update your code to reproduce the image as shown in your question? The code uses lines and not a frame, no background colour and the text is slightly different. The image does not seem to be created from the code you show us.

If I fix all the syntax error in your code in order to be able to compile it, I get  https://i.sstatic.net/LhAMIZHd.png which does not look related to the question at all

Thanks for your effort and kind reminder, codes and remarks are updated.

Did you test your code? The ======================================= will prevent compilation


the ===== in the preamble will cause an error
typo in umbers
the syntax \begin{lstlisting}[html] is wrong. Do you mean [style=html] or [language=HTML]?
the breaklines option works if one removes \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}:


\documentclass[
    ngerman,
        11pt,
    %twoside,
    BCOR=8mm,
    headings=normal,
    parskip=half,
    headsepline,
    automark,
    listof=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
    %,captions=tableabove
    %draft
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
%%%\usepackage{babel}
%
\ifluatex
 % LuaLaTeX
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 % \setmainfont{Arial}
 \usepackage{selnolig}
\else
 % PdfLaTeX
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
%
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlang1}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl} 

\lstdefinestyle{myLaTeX}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=TeX,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    frame=single,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    tabsize=2,
    morekeywords={
        lstdefinestyle,
        footnotesize,
        ttfamily,
        color,
    },
}

\lstdefinestyle{myBasic}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    escapechar={|_},
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
}

\lstset{style=myLaTeX}

%=======================================

\newcommand{\tb}{\textbackslash}
%
\newcommand{\comm}[1]{\enquote{\texttt{\tb #1}}}
%
\newcommand{\param}[1]{%
    $\langle$\textrm{\textit{#1}}$\rangle$%
}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
  language=HTML,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=lines
}

% Define listing settings for HTML
\lstdefinestyle{html}{ 
breaklines=true, 
postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}, 
numbers=left, 
stepnumber=1, 
numbersep=10pt, 
numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
keepspaces=true 
}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=html]
<cite> The order was easy to place and everything was delivered perfectly.</cite>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}



Thanks for the prompt and kind help, even to a stranger, happy weekend!
